# Updating PFUser.currentUser

Tags: swift, parse-platform

For my app the user can change their current username.  So using parse and I set the new username for the current user shown in my code below. I then call `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` to save the new username.  However I get this error "Username already taken." But now `PFUser.currentUser.username` is set to the invalid new username even though the save failed.  I called `fetch` and that didn't change anything.  How can I update the `PFUser.currentUser`?

```
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user.username = newUsernameText
    user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            self.helper.successAlert("Saved!", msg: "Your profile has been updated.")

        } else {
            // There was a problem, check error.description
            self.helper.errorAlert("Error", msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            PFUser.currentUser().fetch()
            self.user = PFUser.currentUser()
            print(user.username) //prints the new username that was invalid

        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess that `print(user.username)` references the `user` on your local scope... How about `print(self.user.username)` or `print(PFUser.currentUser().username)`?

Comment: PFUser.currentUser.username also returns the invalid new username

Comment: try      user["username"] = newUsernameText

Answer (score 1):

Try with changing the username to something totally else. There's a chance you already have the username in your database. Another way of going about this would be to query all existing users first and then to check if the username if taken or not with an `if-else` statement. If it's not update it, if it is throw an alert. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,  i tried that and it worked but the problem is the PFUser.currentUser still carries the new username.  Is there anyway i can update the cached currentUser?